# list of Azure APIs Script

Tags: azure, api, cloud

while trying to gather all AWS APIs I use:

```
> import boto3

# Create a new session
session = boto3.Session()

# Get a list of available services
available_services = session.get_available_services()


# Write the list to a file
with open('aws_services.txt', 'w') as f:
    for service in sorted(available_services):
        f.write(service + '\n')
```

Is/What a similar way of doing it in Azure?

Thanks!

Comment: what does the output of `get_available_services` look like? The Azure REST API has documentation, have you checked it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> Is/What is a similar way of doing it in Azure?

To get the available Azure services and store them in a text file, you can use the Azure SDK for Python and the **`azure-mgmt-resource`** and **`azure-identity`** packages.

First, try to log in with your Azure account using the command in the terminal:

**Command:**

```
az-login
```

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

# Create a ResourceManagementClient using your Azure credentials
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id = 'Your azure subscription ID'
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Retrieve the list of Azure services
providers = resource_client.providers.list()

# Write the list of services to a text file
with open('azure_services.txt', 'w') as f:
    for provider in providers:
        f.write(provider.namespace + '\n')
```

The above code executed and got the available service and stored in **`azure_service.txt`** format.

**Text file.**

[image]

If you need to get the available service without text format you can use the below code:

**Commands:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id = 'Your azure subscription ID'
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
providers = resource_client.providers.list()
for provider in providers:
    print(provider.namespace)
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[azure-samples-python-management/manage_providers.py at main · Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management/blob/main/samples/resources/manage_providers.py)